# Ito's Isometry for bounded integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis

I have to prove that for $f \in \mathcal{H}$, 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^s f_r \, dW_r \int_0^t f_r \, dW_r \right) = \mathbb{E} \int_0^{s \wedge t} f_r^2 \, dr
\end{equation}
for any $s,t \in [0, \infty)$, $s \wedge t =\min(s,t)$.

I am not sure how to apply Ito's isometry to a definite integral like this.

I tried to proceed by rewriting
 $$\int_0^s f_r \, dW_r \int_0^t f_r \, dW_r$ =\int_0^{s \wedge t} 1_{(0, s \wedge t]}f_r \, dW_r \int_0^{s \wedge t} 1_{(0, s \wedge t]}f_r \, dW_r = \left( \int_0^{s \wedge t} 1_{(0, s \wedge t]}f_r \, dW_r \right)^2 $$

and then

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^{s \wedge t} 1_{(0, s \wedge t]}f_r \, dW_r \right)^2 = \int_0^{s \wedge t} \mathbb{E} f_r^2 \, dr
\end{equation}

However, I'm not quite sure about this working. Is it correct? If not, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, but $$\int_0^s f_r \, dW_r \int_0^t f_r \, dW_r$ =\int_0^{s \wedge t} 1_{(0, s \wedge t]}f_r \, dW_r \int_0^{s \wedge t} 1_{(0, s \wedge t]}f_r \, dW_r$$ is obviously wrong, no? For example, if $f_r=1$ almost surely, for every $r$, you are asserting that $$W_sW_t=(W_{s\wedge t})^2$$ which is absurd.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I used the wrong identity - that property is only true for stopping times. I'm still quite new to this, so I am struggling to find my way.

Answer (score 1):

Using the equality: 
$$\int_0^sf_r\,dW_r=\int_0^\infty 1_{]0,s]}(r)f_r\,dW_r,\qquad \text{a.s.}
$$
we have
\begin{align}\mathsf{E}\Bigl[\int_0^sf_r\,dW_r\int_0^tf_r\,dW_r\Bigr]
&=\mathsf{E}\Bigl[\Bigl(\int_0^\infty 1_{]0,s]}(r)f_r\,dW_r\Bigr)\Bigl(\int_0^\infty1_{]0,t]}(r)f_r\,dW_r\Bigr)\Bigr]\\
&=\int_0^\infty1_{]0,s]}(r)f_r1_{]0,t]}(r)f_r\,dr=\int_0^\infty1_{]0,s\wedge t]}(r)f^2_r\,dr\\
&=\int_0^{s\wedge t} f^2_r\,dr.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! I see that I used the wrong identity